# SeekBar setProgressDrawable doesn't work on Android API <= 21

Tags: android

I set my music player Android application minSdkVersion 18. When i test it on API 21 and 19, the color of the progress is not what i expect.
The SeekBar should look like picture 1 but it becomes pictures 2.(I can still click on it but the color seems to be transparent.)

[image]
[image]

The XML code of the SeekBar in the activity layout:

```
<SeekBar
android:id="@+id/seekBar"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="@8dp"
android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/full_time"
android:layout_toRightOf="@id/current_time"
android:layout_marginLeft="@16dp"
android:layout_marginRight="@16dp"
android:layout_centerVertical="true"
android:progressBackgroundTint="#E9E9E9"
android:progress="0"
android:indeterminate="false"
style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
android:progressDrawable="@drawable/seek_bar"/>
```

The seek_bar XML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:id="@android:id/background">
    <shape>
        <corners android:radius="4dip" />
        <solid android:color="#e9e9e9"/>
    </shape>
</item>

<item android:id="@android:id/secondaryProgress">
    <clip>
        <shape>
            <corners android:radius="4dip" />
            <solid android:color="@color/colorPink"/>
        </shape>
    </clip>
</item>

<item android:id="@android:id/progress">
    <clip>
        <shape>
            <corners android:radius="4dip" />
            <solid android:color="@color/colorPink"/>
        </shape>
    </clip>
</item>
```

The line `android:progressDrawable="@drawable/seek_bar"/>` doesn't work on API <=21, even when i write `seekBar.setProgressDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.seek_bar));` in the OnCreate method of the activity. However, if i test on API 23, two ways work perfectly. How can i set the progress color?

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like an SDK level issue. Could this be because `progressBackgroundTint` was added in API 21? Id suggest you to change your minSDK to >=21 and test again.

Comment: It seems it has nothing to do with the progressBackgroundTint. The progress color is shown after I set the thumb color in the xml file on API 21. This is so confusing l. I think the best way is probably adding codes to set the thumb color in lower version.